# Curl and php download file from url not working

Tags: php, curl

I'm trying do retrieve and download a file (image) from a remote location.
Inside the php.ini the allow_url_fopen is enabled, but i can't download the image.
Code i'm using is described below

```
$local_file = "test.jpg";
$remote_file = "http://somehost:6346/cgi-bin/CGIProxy.fcgi?cmd=snapPicture2&usr=xxxx&pwd=xxxx";

$ch = curl_init();
$fp = fopen ($local_file, 'w+');
$ch = curl_init($remote_file);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 50);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FILE, $fp);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_ENCODING, "");
curl_exec($ch);
curl_close($ch);
fclose($fp);
```

with any other url that contains a real jpg file, it's working perfectly, i suppose that the issue is that the url use some special characters that doesn't like to curl.
If i try to execute the php snippet above,page load for almost 1 minute,and it seems that no error are displayed,the image test.jpg is created, but it's empty.
Do you have any suggestion?
Thanks!

Comment: Could you provide image link, maybe there is something on the server side (image extension and...)

Comment: set CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER to true. Also, what does curl_getinfo tell you about the call ?

Comment: ifi try curl_getinfo ,i'am in the same situation of the issue described, it loads for about 1 minute but empty page showed.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
$local_file = "test.jpg";
$remote_file = "http://somehost:6346/cgi-bin/CGIProxy.fcgi?cmd=snapPicture2&usr=xxxx&pwd=xxxx";

function getPage($url) {
        $ch = curl_init();
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, FALSE);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, false);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, true);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_REFERER, $url);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, TRUE);
        $result = curl_exec($ch);
        curl_close($ch);
        return $result;
}
function saveToFile($base, $decode=false, $output_file)
{
        $ifp = fopen($output_file, "wb");
        if ($decode){
          fwrite($ifp, base64_decode($base));
        }else{
          fwrite($ifp, $base);
        }

        fclose($ifp);
        return($output_file);
}

$remote_page = getPage($remote_file);

$saved_file = saveToFile($remote_page , false, $local_file);
```

Comment: It's not working, same issue of the problem described

Comment: send me the full url @user2344562

Comment: Sorry Faxsy i can't since the url contains credentials.
It's an url like this, for an foscam ipcam
http://<id>.myfoscam.org:88/cgi-bin/CGIProxy.fcgi?cmd=snapPicture2&usr=username&pwd=password

Answer (score 0):

when debugging issues like this, set CURLOPT_VERBOSE, it will probably reveal why the page loaded for almost 1 minute, with no apparent output.

`i suppose that the issue is that the url use some special characters` - this is fully possible, for example your username and password, they're supposed to be urlencoded. urlencoding is binary safe, meaning you can have any special characters you'd like, you just need to encode it properly. use urlencode() or http_build_query() for that, eg

```
$remote_file = "http://somehost:6346/cgi-bin/CGIProxy.fcgi?" . http_build_query ( array (
        'cmd' => 'snapPicture2',
        'usr' => 'username',
        'pwd' => 'password' 
) );
```

now http_build_query will properly urlencode any special characters in your username and password (for example, if your username is an email address, the `@` becomes `%40`).

- if that doesn't fix it, what does CURLOPT_VERBOSE say?

also, final note, here you're sending the download request with credentials in a GET request. that's very unusual, the vast majority of websites want you to login with a POST request, and [there are good security-related reasons for that](https://www.fullcontact.com/blog/never-put-secrets-urls-query-parameters/), are you sure your website allows sending credentials in GET parameters? the vast majority of websites doesn't allow it... (and the best way to find out, is to record a browser logging in, does the browser use GET parameters, or POST parameters?)

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion!With your code,it worked 3 times in a row and then nothing..i debugged with CURLOPT_VERBOSEas you suggested and it says a simple " Trying x.x.x.x. * Connection timed out"
It's strange, beacause if i try to open the url with the browser,it opens instantly.... @hanshenrik

Comment: @user2344562 are you running php on the same computer as your web browser, or do you run php on another computer? (eg, a remote server)

Comment: php is on remote server (my hosting), while the url is a ip camera.I tried also to execute the php on my ubuntu station but the result is the same..
@hanshenrik